Let $\alpha $ be a transfinite cardinal number. Prove that the cardinal number $2^\alpha $ is simultaneously even and odd
Let  $\alpha $ be a transfinite cardinal number. Prove that the cardinal
number  $2^\alpha $ is simultaneously even and odd, i.e., $\exists$ cardinal
numbers $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $2^\alpha= 2\beta =2\gamma+1 .$
I tried to solve like this:
since $\alpha$ is transfinite cardinal number then $\alpha -1 > 0 $ and
$2^\alpha  = 2.2.2.2...=2.(2.2.2...)=2.2^{\alpha-1} $
Then we can choose $\beta=2^{\alpha-1}$
But I am not sure about that because we haven't defined the subtraction in cardinal numbers.
Now for another one:
let A is an infinite set and $ \text{Card}(A)= \alpha $
then the power set of A is an infinite set. so it has an infinite countable set. Let we take a $b$ element that $b \notin A \Rightarrow \{b\} \notin P(A) $ then I could prove that there is a bijection between $P(A) \cup \{b\} \text{ and }  P(A)$
But is it true that I can take an element $b$ like this? is it really exist in the general case?

Hint: if a and b are both infinite cardinal, then a+b=a*b=max(a,b). This can be done by drawing bijections.

@LidingYao I have read  that in a book . Actually I tried to prove it and then use it but I didn't know how I can do this for any infinite cardinal numbers

Liding's is a key result.  Once you have it your question is solved with $\beta=\gamma=2^{\alpha}$
